# Security a single view (MVC ASP.NET) with Windows authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, authentication

I'm trying to take away anonymous access to a single view of an MVC application.

I tried to did this by going to the directory (i.e. /views/private) and removing anonymous authentication. This didn't help.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "removing anonymous authentication'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users shouldn't ever visit the physical location of any of your views, so protecting the `views\private` directory wouldn't have any effect. As Developer Art mentioned, security in MVC apps should be done within the controller by using the [Authorize attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx). You can apply that attribute to a controller class or to individual action methods within a controller.

**Edit:** If you're using a view engine that uses files the way the default view engine does, then your entire `views` directory should be protected so that users cannot access any of those files. (Some view engines compile the views into an assembly, so this would not apply.)